# Wanted verification for a proof I completed in the book "Topology Without Tears" (by Sidney A. Morris).

Tags: general-topology

The problem is chapter 2.2, problem 5(ii): Prove the following statement: Let $\mathbb S^1$ be the unit circle given by:
$\mathbb S^1$={$ $$\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$$\in$ $\mathbb R^2$ : $x^2$+$y^2$ $=$ $1$}.
Then $\mathbb S^1$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$.

Here's the proof I made:

Define $A$ as any open disk satisfying $A$ $\cap$ $\mathbb S^1$ $=$ $\emptyset$. Suppose $\alpha$ is the collection of such disks satisfying this property. We want to show that $\bigcup\limits_{A\in\alpha}A$ $=$ $\mathbb R^2$ $\setminus$ $\mathbb S^1$. Suppose $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$ $\in$ $\bigcup\limits_{A\in\alpha}A$. Then clearly $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$ $\in$ $\mathbb R^2$. Since $A$ $\cap$ $\mathbb S^1$ $=$ $\emptyset$ for all $A$ $\in$ $\alpha$, it follows that $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$ $\notin$ $\mathbb S^1$. So $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$ $\in$ $\mathbb R^2$ $\setminus$ $\mathbb S^1$ and $\bigcup\limits_{A\in\alpha}A$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb R^2$ $\setminus$ $\mathbb S^1$. Now suppose $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$ $\in$ $\mathbb R^2$ $\setminus$ $\mathbb S^1$. Then $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$ $\in$ $\mathbb R^2$ and $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$ $\notin$ $\mathbb S^1$. Let $r$ be the distance between the point $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$ and the closest edge of the circle $\mathbb S^1$. Clearly, $r$ $>$ $0$, since if $r$ $=$ $0$, $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$ $\in$ $\mathbb S^1$, which is a contradiction. Let $B$ be the disk (in the textbook, it says this means a circle including all elements within but not on the edges of the circle, in case clarification was needed) with center $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$ and radius $\frac {r}{2}$. Then clearly $B$ $\cap$ $\mathbb S^1$ $=$ $\emptyset$. So $B$ $\in$ $\alpha$ and $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$ $\in$ $\bigcup\limits_{A\in\alpha}A$, since $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$ $\in$ $B$. So $\mathbb R^2$ $\setminus$ $\mathbb S^1$ $\subseteq$ $\bigcup\limits_{A\in\alpha}A$. Therefore, $\bigcup\limits_{A\in\alpha}A$ $=$ $\mathbb R^2$ $\setminus$ $\mathbb S^1$. Since $\mathbb R^2$ $\setminus$ $\mathbb S^1$ is a union of open sets in $\mathbb R^2$, it is open itself. So $\mathbb S^1$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$.

I wanted to make sure my proof is correct, and, if it is, if it is the most efficient proof or if there is an easier way to solve this problem. I apologize by the way if my mathjax looks messy, this is the first time I've used this (or anything latex related).

Comment: What part are you not sure is correct ?

Comment: $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x, y) =x^2+y^2-1$$ is continuous.$$\Bbb{S}^1=f^{-1}[\{0\}]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is very good.

What you could elaborate more on is the "distance between the point $\langle a,b\rangle$ and the closest edge of the circle $\mathbb S^1$". How do you know the distance is nonzero? In fact, this fact is sort-of equivalent to what you want to prove in the first place. Imagine if the question was not about $\mathbb S^1$ but about some set that is not closed: say, about the open disc $B(\langle 0,0\rangle, 1)$: the point $\langle 1,0\rangle$ is not on the disc but its distance from the disc is zero!

You can see that there is that hole in your proof because you didn't use the exact nature of $\mathbb S^1$ anywhere in your proof.

To fill the gap, let $O=\langle 0,0\rangle$ and let's first notice that $\mathbb S^1=\{X\in\mathbb R^2\mid d(O,X)=1\}$. Now, let $A=\langle a,b\rangle\not\in\mathbb S^1$. This means that $d(O,A)\ne 1$. Distinguish two cases:

1. $d(O,A)>1$. If you set $d=d(O,A)-1>0$, then $B(A,d)$ does not intersect $\mathbb S^1$. This is because if there *was* a point $X$ contained in both $\mathbb S^1$ and $B(A,d)$, then the *triangle inequality* would be broken for the points $O,X,A$, since $d(O,A)=1+d>\underbrace{d(O,X)}_1+\underbrace{d(X,A)}_{<d}$.
2. $d(O,A)<1$. This is very similar (left as an exercise for you). In this case, take $d=1-d(O,A)$.

---

As for alternative proofs, the more you already know, the easier the proof. You may have heard the theorem stating that "the preimage of a closed set in a continuous function is closed". So, if your *continuous* function is $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(\langle x,y\rangle)=x^2+y^2$, you only need to notice that $\mathbb S^1=f^{-1}(\{1\})$ and that $\{1\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: For your case 2, taking $B_1(O)$ suffices as an open neighborhood of $A$ and avoids a second triangle inequality argument.

Comment: @erfink I guess it all hangs on what the OP is doing at that point in the proof. I understand that they want a disc _centred_ in $\langle a,b\rangle$, and, if so, they may need a more elaborate construction. Otherwise, you are right.

Comment: I guess in my proof I didn't make it clear what I was doing. If I show that a particular set, in this case, the complement of the circle in $\mathbb R^2$, is equal to the union of open disks (which a previous problem showed was open in $\mathbb R^2$), then shouldn't that show that the set is open? The way I proceeded was by showing that the union of such sets and the complement were subsets of eachother, which I assume is done by assuming an element is in one set and showing it must be in another. In which case, if I assume an element <a, b> is in the complement, it can't be in $\mathbb S^1$.

Comment: @TimothyBennett Replace "$\mathbb S^1$ with some other set that is _not_ closed. Say, $B(O, 1)$. Now there _are_ points at distance $0$ of the set which are not in the set. Proving that there are no such points for $\mathbb S^1$ is the very essence of proving that $\mathbb S^1$ is closed. So how do you prove $d>0$? - that is the question. *I don't dispute anything else in your proof.*

Comment: I see what you mean, I assume I would do something involving the specific formula for the set $\mathbb S^1$ and $r$? Sometimes I'm not sure if I should be more rigorous or less rigorous, but I see that part of my proofs problem is it doesn't directly include the set in question in the proof.

Comment: I understand. We've all been there: every time some theory starts to get developed, and as it gets developed from the first principles, it is hard to track what has been proven at each step and which "obvious" things have already been covered and which ones have yet to be proven...  As you go on and the theory solidifies, you will be at the stage where you will be able to prove all those obvious things yourself, after which you  treat all of them as given and you stop worrying which one follows from which.

Answer (score 2):

I’m worried that you’ve already relied on the fact it’s closed when you say ‘clearly $r>0$ because if $r=0$ then t would be in $S^1$’ - that’s just a property of closed sets. The proof hasn’t really made specific reference to any properties of characterisation of $S^1$, it’s just a correct proof of the fact that “$d(x,K)>0$ for all $x$ not in $K$ implies $K$ is closed”.

You might be able to fix this if you can rigorously prove the distance of a point to $S^1$ is *attained* somewhere on the circle (rigorously prove this thing about ‘the closest edge’).

But that’s actually related to the fact $S^1$ is compact! One quick way to see $S^1$ is compact and therefore closed is to note it is the continuous image of $[0,1]$ - which is compact - under $x\mapsto(\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x))$. I would think of this as the efficient proof.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment; posting as an answer.

Your proof is okayish, but is a bit circuitous and has a couple sticking points:

- For $\langle a,b\rangle \in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{S}^1$, how do you know that there exists $r>0$ that is "the distance between $\langle a,b \rangle$ and the closest edge of the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$." This could be made rigorous, but you are presupposing a lot of information.
- "Define $A$ as any open disk satisfying $A \cup \mathbb{S}^1 \neq \emptyset$. Suppose $\alpha$ is the collection of such disks satisfying this property." How do you know *a priori* that any such $A$ exists? Does your proof still hold if $\alpha=\emptyset$?

Recognizing $\mathbb{S}^1$ as the continuous image of a compact set and hence compact per the answer of @FShrike is quite efficient if you have access to that tool.

If you want to proceed from first principles as you have done, I would sketch as follows:

1. We will show that $\mathbb{S}^1$ is closed by establishing that its complement $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{S}^1$ is open. <--Brings our structure to the forefront.
2. $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathbb{S}^1 = B_1(0,0) \cup \left( \mathbb{R}^2\setminus D^2\right)$, where $D^2$ is the **closed** disk of radius 1 about the origin (**why?**). Then $B_1(0,0)$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus D^2$ are both open (**why?**) and we recognize $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathbb{S}^1$ as the union of open sets and hence open as well. QED

Comment: What does $B_1(0,0)$ mean?

Comment: @TimothyBennett $B_r(x,y)$ is the open ball (=disk) of radius $r$ centered at $(x,y)$. So $B_1(0,0)$ is the open ball (=disk) of radius 1 about the origin.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks!